# Format output by two decimal digits and separate decimals by five spaces

Tags: java, printf

My code for the statement I want to print is the following:

```
System.out.printf("%-5s.2f %5s %14s %5s\n", months[x], avg[x]((avg[x]-variation)*100.0)/100.0, "Above");
```

My output is:

```
Months Average Variations
Jan .2f 13.3 1.7299999999999986 Below
```

I need to format the number under "variations" by two decimals instead of getting an unnecessary amount of decimals, but I also need to space it out so that it is formatted appropriately. I don't need to upload the rest of the code, this is the only thing that keeps my program from working.

Comment: Have you tried [NumberFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html)?

Comment: I don't believe that that line of code corresponds to that output...

Comment: I have not, but I'm very new to programming and I'm trying to just use printf for this program.

Comment: Doesn't work if I cast as float.

Comment: I don't understand `separate decimals by five spaces`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood the question correctly, but maybe this code does what you want?

```
System.out.println("Months Average Variations");
System.out.printf("%-5s.2f %5s %12.2f %5s\n", "Jan", 13.3, 1.7299999999999986, "Below");
```

Output:

```
Months Average Variations
Jan  .2f  13.3         1.73 Below
```

And, it is always useful to research the Internet before asking on StackOverflow, for example, you could read [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html) about formatting numbers (and JavaDoc of [Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) class).